# Amazon EC2 Drupal 6 Site

Tags: amazon-ec2, drupal-6

Before anything, I have never worked with Amazon EC2 Service, first time I even hear of it. I was asked to work on a Drupal 6 site and I need to upload a custom module. The client gave me a username and password to log into Amazon EC2, but told me nothing else. I assumed their site was hosted there. I came upon the EC2 dashboard, and to my surprise (or maybe not) there were no **running instances**. If I understood properly, you need a running instance that's supposed to work as the server, please, correct me if I'm wrong. I might be understanding it all wrong, and associating "instance" as if it were the Virtual Server itself (sort of like when you use virtual machines on your computer and instance=="virtual machine").

If there are no running instances, how is the site "up" ? There must be a server, somewhere, answering to the client's requests. Or is it that the "instances" are more like "working sessions"? Thing is, I don't want to meddle too much into the dashboard in case I mess it up since this client has no staging site nor repository. That's why I wasn't bold enough to create an instance.

Helps is much appreciated.

Comment: Are you logged in to the correct Region? Ask your client what the region is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct, that if the site is hosted on aws ec2, there must be an ec2 instance running somewhere - definitely check to make sure you have selected the correct region in the upper right hand corner of the console.

The only other possibility, and I don't this would apply to Drupal, is it actually is possible to host an html/css/javascript only site completely on aws s3 (which would not required ec2 instance) but that is not likely what you are dealing with.

[image]

Comment: The problem was the Region chosen. Kudos!